# OpenCV in Python: Rectangle with fill and stroke in one loop

Tags: python, opencv, graphics, drawing, game-automation

## OpenCV rectangle fill & stroke in a single loop

### Introduction

Hi! I'm trying to add a rectangle with a translucent fill and a solid stroke over template matches in OpenCV with Python. The material I'm working with is from a game called [**Sun Haven**](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1432860/Sun_Haven) by Pixel Sprout Studios, found on [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com).

### Setup

**Operating System**: Microsoft Windows 11

**Python version**: 3.10.4

**OpenCV version**: 4.7.0

### Problem

Currently, I have a script that will do the trick, but I don't like the way it's implemented as I currently have to loop through template results twice:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load the haystack and needle images in OpenCV.
haystack_image = cv.imread('sun_haven_14.jpg', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
needle_image = cv.imread('sun_haven_beecube.jpg', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Haystack image with drawings on.
scribble_image = haystack_image.copy()

# Grab the dimensions of the needle image.
needle_width = needle_image.shape[1]
needle_height = needle_image.shape[0]

# Match the needle image against the the haystack image.
result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_image, needle_image, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

# Define a standard to which a result is assumed positive.
threshold = 0.5

# Filter out image locations where OpenCV falls below the confidence threshold.
locations = np.where(result >= threshold)

# Convert the locations from arrays to X/Y-coordinate tuples.
locations = list(zip(*locations[::-1]))

# Debug-print the locations to the console.
#print(locations)

rectangles = []

# For all the locations found...
for location in locations:
    # Define a rectangle to draw around the location.
    rectangle = [int(location[0]), int(location[1]), needle_width, needle_height]

    # Append the rectangle to the rectangle collection.
    rectangles.append(rectangle)

# Group duplicate rectangles from overlapping results.
rectangles, weights = cv.groupRectangles(rectangles, 1, 1)

# If we have any rectangles at all...
if len(rectangles):
    print('Found needle(s)!')
    
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        # Determine the location position.
        top_left = (rectangle[0], rectangle[1])
        bottom_right = (rectangle[0] + rectangle[2], rectangle[1] + rectangle[3])

        # Draw a transparent, filled rectangle over the detected needle image.
        cv.rectangle(scribble_image, top_left, bottom_right, color = (0, 255, 0), thickness = -1)

    result_image = cv.addWeighted(scribble_image, 0.25, haystack_image, 1 - 0.25, 0)

    for rectangle in rectangles:
        # Determine the location position.
        top_left = (rectangle[0], rectangle[1])
        bottom_right = (rectangle[0] + rectangle[2], rectangle[1] + rectangle[3])

        # Draw a solid line around the detected needle image.
        cv.rectangle(result_image, top_left, bottom_right, color = (0, 255, 0), thickness = 2, lineType = cv.LINE_4)

    # Display the image in a window.
    cv.imshow('Result', result_image)
else:
    print('No needle found...')

# Pause the script.
cv.waitKey()

# Destroy all the OpenCV 2 windows.
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'd prefer to combine the two "for rectangle in rectangles"-loops into a single loop, but if I do, I'm only getting the fill and not the stroke around the results.

### Images

#### Haystack image (sun_haven_14.jpg)

[image: Sun Haven. Credits: Pixel Sprout Studios]

#### Needle image (sun_haven_beecube.jpg)

[image: Beecube from Sun Haven. Credits: Pixel Sprout Studios]

#### OpenCV script results (desired outcome)

[image: The desired result, but with poor code.]

As you can see, this detects and highlights the four beecubes from the original image, but I'd rather merge the two loops to not repeat the rectangle iteration and for performance.

### Desired change

I've tried merging the two loops into this:

```
for rectangle in rectangles:
    # Determine the location position.
    top_left = (rectangle[0], rectangle[1])
    bottom_right = (rectangle[0] + rectangle[2], rectangle[1] + rectangle[3])

    # Draw a transparent, filled rectangle over the detected needle image.
    cv.rectangle(scribble_image, top_left, bottom_right, color = (0, 255, 0), thickness = -1)

    # Draw a solid line around the detected needle image.
    cv.rectangle(scribble_image, top_left, bottom_right, color = (0, 255, 0), thickness = 2, lineType = cv.LINE_4)

result_image = cv.addWeighted(scribble_image, 0.25, haystack_image, 1 - 0.25, 0)

# Display the image in a window.
cv.imshow('Result', result_image)
```

However, this does not yield the results I'm looking for, as it will only draw the transparent fill, not the stroke:
[image: Undesired results with fill, but no stroke.]

So am I stuck with two almost identical for-loops, or is there a way to do this in a single loop?
I'd really like to not repeat something that only needs to be done once, but if I have to, I have to.

Looking forward to feedback, cheers!

Comment: Because you draw the lines on scribble_image and then use addWeighted to add it on top of the original, the lines now also get added transparently in the merged loop example. Have you considered using a different alpha value on the rectangles, and not using addWeighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Thanks to feedback from [@Grismar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4390160/grismar), I now avoid drawing the solid-line rectangles on the same layer as the transparent fill rectangles, but instead draw directly on the haystack image:

```
for rectangle in rectangles:
    # Determine the location position.
    top_left = (rectangle[0], rectangle[1])
    bottom_right = (rectangle[0] + rectangle[2], rectangle[1] + rectangle[3])

    # Draw a transparent, filled rectangle over the detected needle image.
    cv.rectangle(scribble_image, top_left, bottom_right, color = (0, 255, 0), thickness = -1)

    # Draw a solid line around the detected needle image.
    cv.rectangle(haystack_image, top_left, bottom_right, color = (0, 255, 0), thickness = 2, lineType = cv.LINE_4)

result_image = cv.addWeighted(scribble_image, 0.25, haystack_image, 1 - 0.25, 0)

# Display the image in a window.
cv.imshow('Result', result_image)
```

Comment: Your comment in the code about drawing a "transparent" rectangle is misleading.  Your code show a green rectangle being drawn.

Comment: Yes, fmw42. I see it now. It's just a normal filled rectangle that is about to become transparent with the addWeighted function.